# Web Platform Installer 5.0 start error. 'version' start tag on line 118400

Tags: windows-server-2012, web-platform-installer

On a non-activated Windows 2012 VM template, I get the following error when trying to launch the Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0.

```
The 'version' start tag on line 118400 position 8 does not match the end
tag of 'entry'. Line 118437, position 7.
```

What causes this problem? Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Just got this error myself.

Comment: same here :The 'version' start tag on line 118400 does not match the end tag of 'entry'. Line 118437, position 7.

Comment: fyi: resetting as described in this post does not seem to help.  Microsoft must have just changed something on their end.  (http://forums.iis.net/post/2069685.aspx)

Comment: [Found this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1207743.aspx?WPI+4+6+Error+loading+downloaded+product+file+in+log+file) but I can't find the XML File in question. Looking in Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer

Comment: Generally speaking a good place for more information are a couple posts http://forums.iis.net/1155.aspx/1?Web+Platform+Installer relating to this error (near the top, so this comment will eventually be obsolete).

Comment: I am no longer getting an error when browsing to the XML file manually and opening the installer. Guess Microsoft quietly updated it. Anyone else fixed now?

Comment: @tnw: same here! I have no idea how to close this question now in a "StackExchange way" ;)

Comment: I deleted the logs folder located at ..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\ and was then able to run the Web Platform Installer without any problems. But tnw pointed out I did this about the time that the issue seemed to have cleared up.

Comment: @dstj, I don't think there is any reason to actually close the question. ncole's answer documents what happened, so leaving it selected seems logical to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The xml feed has now been fixed so everything is good.  There is no need to delete log files or anything.**

```
The 'version' start tag on line 118400 does not match the end tag of 'entry'. 
Line 118437, position 7.
```

I looked at the log file located at **\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\webpi** and it references the xml file [webproductlist.xml](https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml).  This xml file does not seem to be valid.  It looks like this one is on Microsoft for the moment.

**The xml feed has now been fixed so everything is good.  There is no need to delete log files or anything.**

Comment: Hello and welcome to the StackExchange sites.  Normally answers are reserved  for answering (obviously).  Also, as others have already said that, you're not really providing any new information.  So you know, this answer will probably be deleted once a mod comes along.

Comment: Yes... I would love to add it as a comment, but it wouldn't let me because I'm a new user.  But I know that sometimes it can be useful to know that others are having the same problem and at the time I posted this no other comments had been left yet.  Thank you for being polite in your response.  That is not always how it goes.

Comment: Your edit is indeed correct, both Chrome and IE bomb out when going to that link. It's malformed XML.

Comment: Feel free to vote me up so I can actually make comments in the future as well! :-)

Comment: Thank you folks.  I'm just glad we can all get back to work now!